# Is redirect a second request?

Tags: node.js, http, express, httprequest

I'm trying to keep form data with old data. Todo so, I have created a simple middleware:

```
  /*
  * Mapa para manter os valores dos campos get e post
  */
  res.locals.old = new Map();
  /*
  * Cria uma entrada no mapa para cada parametro get e post
  */
  const query_body = Object.assign({}, req.body, req.query);
  Object.keys(query_body).forEach(key => {
    res.locals.old.set(key, query_body[key]);
  });
  console.log('Parâmetros get e post:', query_body);
```

Then, in the console I get this:

[image]

The only thing I can presume is that the post parameters are been stored correctly, but the redirect in the controller is generating a second get request that makes the map get empty again. If it's work this way, how can I keep post data in the locals without explicity use session?

Hope you understand, I don't speak english. Thank you very much.

Comment: This seems to be related and may answer your question: [Why doesn't HTTP have POST redirect?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect) Actually it does, and the accepted answer explains.

Comment: I kind of got it, but the fact is that I don't want to keep the method to post in the redirect. It's fine for me to do de get after the post (302?) but I need to keep the req.body the same, can I inject that body in the redirect request?

Comment: Why not just POST directly to the final URL? There isn't really a good reason to POST to a page that redirects, it sort of indicates an underlying issue.

Comment: The post cames form a form to create (modify database) an entry on the database, but if the data is not valid (checked by mongoose) I need to redirect back to the previous page.. For now I'm trying a middleware called connection-flash to keep the post data.